# Issue a redirect, trying several string replacements for the domain

Tags: c#, .net, url

How could I improve this code?

```
var to = "http://forum.";

if (!RedirectPermanent("http://www.", to))
    if (!RedirectPermanent("http://blog.", to))
        if (!RedirectPermanent("http://forum.", to))
            if (!RedirectPermanent("http://tracker.", to))
                if (!RedirectPermanent("http://wiki.", to))
                    RedirectPermanent("http://", to);
```

This is the method:

```
private bool RedirectPermanent(string from,string to)
{
    if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(from))
    {
        var domain = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Replace(from, to);
        Response.RedirectPermanent(string.Concat(domain, Request.RawUrl));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Went for this:

```
var arr = new[] { "http://www.", "http://blog.", "http://forum.", "http://tracker.", "http://wiki.", "http://" };
var to = "http://forum.";

foreach (var from in arr)
{
    if (RedirectPermanent(from, to))
        break;
}
```

Comment: Slight criticism, use better variable names.  Expand it to `redirectSources`, `redirectTo` and `redirectFrom`.  And in general, don't use contextual keywords as variable names such as `from`, even though safe, you should treat it like any other keywords and avoid it all together.

Answer (score 1):

#### Review

- That level of nesting hurts readability.
- There is a lack of re-usability for a common set of source urls to redirect.
- You have specified an ultimate fallback of `http://`. But what if we encounter `https://` or `ftp://`?

#### Alternative

As suggested by others, you want to loop a collection of input values and break on first match. The way I would do it is to provide a utility method. Use a `HashSet` to avoid duplicates.

```
private bool RedirectPermanent(HashSet<string> redirectSources, string redirectTo)
{
    return redirectSources.Any(x => RedirectPermanent(x, redirectTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation:

```
var arr = new[] { "http://www.", "http://blog.", "http://forum.", "http://tracker.", "http://wiki.", "http://" };   
var to = "http://forum.";

int i = 0;

while ((!RedirectPermanent(from[i], to)) && i < arr.Length)
{
    ++i; // reversed from i++
    if (i > arr.length) { break; }
}
```

There are several reasons I prefer this over a `foreach`:

- `foreach` has a performance cost to execute. An internal state machine iterator has to be instantiated. The `while` with a count limiter essentially does the same thing. While this is a performance tweak, IMO, it's still a better practice.
- code is not restricted/limited by the locked state of the iterated collection or the state machine iterator.
- IMO, using `foreach` with a body of `if-then-break` smells and reads like slang rather than proper grammar. ;)

Comment: This may have been different 8 years ago, but nowadays a `foreach` loop over an _array_ produces IL bytecode that is quite similar to that for a `for` or `while` loop - in this case a `foreach` loop is even slightly faster. More importantly, it's less error-prone: your loop fails with an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if none of the redirects is successful.

Comment: A `foreach` loop does use an enumerator for other collection types, and that might be a bit slower. On the other hand, it works with any type that has an appropriate `GetEnumerator` method, it's easy to get right, and the intent is clear. The restrictions you mention are not inherent to `foreach`, they're an intentional safety mechanism in the enumerators of most BCL collection types.

Comment: Fair enough; I was only somewhat aware that optimizations had occurred in compiling `foreach` (and other loop/enumerator ops). As far as restrictions go, regardless of the purpose - safety, whatever - they are still restrictions and I agree with the need for safeguards. Added check for 'out of range'.

Comment: Your new out-of-range check is also broken...